# Trying to retrieve a (Firestore) document from a nested collection with Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have been working with Angular for a while, but is very new to FireStore and fairly reactive programming. 
I’ve tried several versions of this below procedure but has now run out of options. Also look at all similar questions on StackO.

I have a working service (Observable) to retrieve the parent document of the nested collection. The only difference is that I have to get the Id to the parent (user) document. My console logs show that I retrieve the right document id.

My problem is that the second section of code (2) is not run at all. My first take was to use an observable, but it did not work. Any help appreciated.
One more quest. Is it better to use the original FS SDK than Augularfire2?

(Sorry updated the snippet since I saw that I used a test version)

```js
  getHealthProfile() {
    const myprom = new Promise(resolve => {
      this._authSubscription = this.userDbService
        .setUserDocIdByEmail()
        .subscribe(users => {
          const id = users[0].id.trim();
          this.userDoc = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${id}`);
          console.log(this.userDoc); // CORRECT PATH 
          (2) this.userDoc
          .collection('healthProfile')
          .doc('HP')
          .snapshotChanges().map(action => {
           console.log('map'); // Result…NOTHING
            if (action.payload.exists === false) {
              console.log('null'); // Result … NOTHING
              return null;
            } else {
              console.log('else data'); //Result … NOTHING
              const data = action.payload.data() as HealthProfile;
              data.id = action.payload.id;
              resolve(data);
            }
          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try `map` instead of `.subscribe` in `.setUserDocIdByEmail()
        .subscribe`

Comment: Thx will do, but found out that I could use a known id for the parent document, so I changed my create of the parent to set instead of add. Now it works fine. I will test U'r proposal.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)